# My Unity 2D player controller script won't make my character flip when he moves to a different direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, flip

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool facingRight = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;

    }

}
```

I'm made a c# 2D player controller script to use in unity, but when I hit play, my player won't flip and face a different direction when he moves a different direction. Can anyone spot what's wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Was just a dumb bug. I put an outdated AND updated script component into my player. Yes I know I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Unity seems a good choice to developp your game but due to the simplicity of your game, i think it will be easier to create it using Android Studio, it is more easier to handler Character Sprite and Animation. All depend of what kind of game you want to create.

"""For instances guys, i create a simple SkaterBoard game using simple gravity physics with Android Studio, I would really appreciate if you could left a review on it."""

(Android Link) Skater Soldier Game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fight.exempleclass

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure you double check settings, values, and where you attached scripts : )

I've heard a couple people advise against flipping via scale and instead prefer :

```
transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
```

Or depending on the gameplay / utility needed using [SpriteRenderer.flipX](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html)

In case you'd like alternatives.